# How can I build a minimal static version of grpc for C/C++

Tags: grpc

Need to build a version of grpc with just static libs. Without plugin support and not building shared libraries. I cant seem to find a way. I'm also using a custom version of SSL and system zlib and have set the required

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DgRPC_ZLIB_PROVIDER=package -DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=package -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=<path to my ssl root>
```

Running on CentOS7 although this seems it should be a platform agnostic request/feature.

I dont need to do a make install as we check the binaries into our source tree so that the rest of our project will build and then link this static version of grpc and our custom ssl.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, I'm trying to find the answer to a minimal C/C++ protobuf/grpc setup myself for a container build. I don't need all the support for all the other languages.

Secondly, checking your binaries into a source code repository? Really? You should be using something like bintray, artifactory, nexus etc. for that.

Comment: RE: Secondly. Not my call how we checkin/manage binaries and such. Above my paygrade. I did get the minimal build working.

Comment: I know what you mean about the infrastructure. Maybe suggest it? You may be thanked. That's good news about the build. Any chance you could share how you did it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question, though in my case I was trying to figure out how to do it in Windows.  I wanted static libs but linked against dynamic runtime (`/MD` versus `/MT`.)

Tried to build gRPC myself.  Eventually went the [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) route, which is so much better, especially when working with open source software in Windows!

However, on Windows vcpkg only builds 2 things by default:  fully dynamic, or fully static.  What I wanted was static libs linked against the dynamic runtime.  To do that you have to create your own triplet.  Here is how I did it:

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
cd vcpkg
bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
vcpkg integrate install
vcpkg integrate powershell
cd triplets
copy x64-windows.cmake x64-windows-mixed.cmake
```

Edit `x64-windows-mixed.cmake` so it contains these 3 lines:

```
set(VCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE x64)
set(VCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE dynamic)
set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE static)
```

Then install and build both gRPC & protobufs:

```
cd ..
vcpkg.exe install grpc:x64-windows-mixed protobuf:x64-windows-mixed
```

If you are on Linux, then it looks like the default triplet may already be correct, since the `x64-linux.cmake` file defaults to:

```
set(VCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE x64)
set(VCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE dynamic)
set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE static)
set(VCPKG_CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
```

Once you have everything built in vcpkg, you'll want to customize your own project's cmake file to look for the correct software, and link in the right `.a` files.  I didn't try this on linux, but in Windows my project includes the following:

```
FIND_PACKAGE ( protobuf CONFIG  REQUIRED )
FIND_PACKAGE ( c-ares   CONFIG  REQUIRED )
FIND_PACKAGE ( gRPC     CONFIG  REQUIRED )
FIND_PACKAGE ( ZLIB             REQUIRED )
FIND_PACKAGE ( OpenSSL          REQUIRED )
FIND_PACKAGE ( Threads          REQUIRED )
```

To ensure I have the correct vcpkg include directory, I used this:

```
FIND_PATH ( SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIR zlib.h )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ( ${SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIR} )
```

And then when linking, I make sure `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` includes the following:

```
PUBLIC Threads::Threads
protobuf::libprotoc protobuf::libprotobuf protobuf::libprotobuf-lite
gRPC::gpr gRPC::grpc gRPC::grpc++ gRPC::grpc_cronet
c-ares::cares c-ares::cares_static
OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL::Crypto
ZLIB::ZLIB )
```

When you first run cmake, remember to specify the toolchain file and prefix path.  In my case on Windows I also had to tell it which triplet to use.  The command looked like this:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake \
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug \
  -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/src/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake \
  -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/src/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows-mixed \
  -DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows-mixed \
  ..
```

(That last command cannot be broken up that way in Windows, I only did that here to help show the parameters I'm passing in.)